# iphone fading of images

Tags: objective-c, xcode

wat i want is to show an image in image view and fade the image after 5 seconds and show the next image .the images are  stored in an array objects...i was able to make a successful transition between images after 5 seconds.what i want is to fadeout the first image after 5 seconds and show the next one this got to happen in an infinite loop...below is the code and it works really good for normal transition between images..wat i want is fading of images...and were to add fading transition in the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    imgView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"lori.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"miranda.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"taylor.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingrid.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"kasey.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"wreckers.png"], nil];


    imgView.animationDuration=20.0;
    imgView.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [imgView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];



    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a repeating NSTimer to call a special method which animates the image views alpha property from 0.0 to 1.0 continuously. Here is some code I have written which works:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    imgView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"lori.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"miranda.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"taylor.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingrid.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"kasey.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"wreckers.png"], nil];



    imgView.animationDuration=20.0;
    imgView.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [imgView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
    //The timers time interval is the imageViews animation duration devided by the number of images in the animationImages array. 20/5 = 4 
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:4.0 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [timer fire];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

//It is important that the animation durations within these animation blocks add up to 4 
//(the time interval of the timer). If you change the time interval then the time intervals 
//in these blocks must also be changed to refelect the amount of time an image is displayed. 
//Failing to do this will mean your fading animation will go out of phase with the switching of images.   

-(void)onTimer{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            imgView.alpha = 0.0; 
        }];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            imgView.alpha = 1.0; 
        }];
    }
```

If you want the fade duration to last for 5 seconds instead of 4, you need to increase your image views animationDuration property to 25, and then increase the fade animation durations in the two blocks such that the sum fade time = 5.

Comment: both animations would start immediately and concurrently, wouldn't they? you'd better use animateWithDuration:animations:completion: where the second animation gets fired on the completion of the first animation. And I set animation durations so that it fits imageview changing images duration. Or change images manually in the onTimer method, which is better if it animates from code anyway.

Comment: @saman:i tried the above code i was able to get the fading effect.what i want is the first image to fade away and show the next one and the seconde fade away show the next....etc wat i m getting is fading of the first image sudden transition of the second and then second image fading after certain millisecond still showing the second image den sudden transition of the third...cud u help me out

Comment: Do you mean that as the current image fades out, you want the next image to fade in? So that it doesnt fade to white, it fades directly into the next image?

Comment: yup....the thing wat i m getting is the first image fades in..shows the next image out of sudden.. the second image fades out to white and shows the third after 2 millisecond

Comment: You need two image views, one on top of the other, so that when the top most image view fades out the image view on the layer bellow appears.

Comment: how should i start with.. if i m to implement with two image views...coz i ve stored all my images in an array

Answer (score 3):

@user652878 This answeres your question regarding fading seemlessly from one image to the next:

Create the following properties in your view controllers header:

```
UIImageView *imageViewBottom, *imageViewTop;
    NSArray *imageArray;
```

Then add this code to your implimentaion file:

```
int topIndex = 0, prevTopIndex = 1; 
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    imageViewBottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageViewBottom]; 

    imageViewTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageViewTop];

    imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"lori.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"miranda.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"taylor.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingrid.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"kasey.png"], 
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wreckers.png"], nil];


    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [timer fire];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)onTimer{
    if(topIndex %2 == 0){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^
        {
            imageViewTop.alpha = 0.0;
        }]; 
        imageViewTop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:prevTopIndex];
        imageViewBottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:topIndex];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^
         {
             imageViewTop.alpha = 1.0;
         }];    
        imageViewTop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:topIndex];
        imageViewBottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:prevTopIndex];
    }
    prevTopIndex = topIndex; 
    if(topIndex == [imageArray count]-1){
        topIndex = 0; 
    }else{
        topIndex++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @samanB:dude hats off..worked fine...but the thing is after the third image the app quits..cud u help me wid dis

Comment: Can you please paste the call stack and error you are getting when it crashes. Without that there is almost nothing I can do to help you.

Comment: samanB:there is error or crash in the console..its jst that it shows the 3 images perfectly and then quits

Comment: U have no error in console? That code runs fine for me, check that all the image file names are correct, if you have an error in a string, it will cause the program to crash. Check the 4th image in the array as it shows the first 3 fine.

Comment: @saman:dude long time no see...i tried the above code for 3 images the app crashes giving an error in the console that NSInvalidArgumentException-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]:Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e..cud u help me .

Comment: Hi. Can you email me your code please? just what is in viewDidLoad() My email is on my profile.

Comment: cud u send me ur email id..der is only a website link

Comment: dude... u ve got your companys website link...www.innovation-stream.com....der is no email id

Comment: dude i was able to fix the bug..i dint release image array in dealloc  since the image array is autorealease...it was accessing the garbage the transition works fine but got another problem...

Comment: its like dis...i have placed a tableview in uiviewcontroller and above the tableview i m doing the fading of images..i m getting the fading transition infinitly but the entire view is frozen..if i m to use an NSoperation or (threading) of the above fading of images..i m getting the transition of first two images untill the web data gets loaded in the table view..after the webdata gets loaded in table view the fading transition is stoped and the frozen view is released(i m able to acess tableview stuff)...wat i want is fading of images to occour infinetly at the same time access other stuff

Comment: @Sabobin, just wondering when the topIndex start from 0, it will just jump back without any animation, anyway to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me when I wanted to animate a set of messages as images to the user. No matter how many images you have this code will rotate through them.

```
[self.messageBottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(289, 262, 171, 38)];
[self addSubview:messageBottom];
[messageBottom setAlpha:0.0];
[messageBottom release];

self.messageTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(289, 262, 171, 38)];
[self addSubview:messageTop];
[messageTop setAlpha:1.0];
[messageTop release];


self.messageImgsArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"],nil];


topIndex = 0, bottomIndex = 1;     
[messageTop setImage:[messageImgsArray objectAtIndex:topIndex]];

//The timers time interval is the imageViews animation duration devided by the number of images in the animationImages array. 20/5 = 4 
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}


-(void)onTimer{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

        //set the image of the image that is not currently visible

        if (messageTop.alpha == 0) {
            [messageTop setImage:[messageImgsArray objectAtIndex:topIndex]];
        }
        if (messageBottom.alpha == 0) {
            [messageBottom setImage:[messageImgsArray objectAtIndex:bottomIndex]];
        }

        //make sure the images rotate
        [messageTop setAlpha:messageTop.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0];
        [messageBottom setAlpha:messageBottom.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0];

        //make sure the images play in a loop

        topIndex = topIndex < [messageImgsArray count]-1 ? bottomIndex+1 : 0;
        bottomIndex = bottomIndex < [messageImgsArray count]-1 ? bottomIndex+1 : 0;

    }];
}
```

Comment: how can i stop it after i.e 3 times?