# iOS Looping Image Slideshow

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation, slideshow

I have around 30 images. I want to have a slideshow running of these images without user intervention. Prime requirements are -

1. image1 fadesIn, displays for 20 seconds, image1 fadesOut - image2 FadesIn etc. All this happens automatically. No user intervention.
2. Also when we reach the last image, image20. The slideshow loops back to the first image.
3. This slideshow might have other elements also like `UILabel`. So it's just not image slideshow.

My biggest problem is how to chain 20 images into this fadein/fadeout animation? How do we get this done in iOS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618964/iphone-fading-of-images

Comment: @MattiasWadman thanks for the link. the slideshow might not be just images. If it was your link is perfect. What if I want to show `UILabel` like this? fadein a `label` while fading out other `label` or `image`? have updated the question in point3

Comment: Then I would probably create separate `UIView`:s for each "image" that could contain labels, images etc and then animate between them using the `alpha` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an UIView containing a different UIImageView for each image you have to show on your slideshow and create a nested animation block. Something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                 animations:^{ /* animations */ } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                                                               animations:^{ /* animations */ } 
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){ [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                                                                                                             animations:^{ /* animations */ } 
                                                                                                             completion:^(BOOL finished){}]; }]; }];
```

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a small framework that does exactly that, feel free to use it :
https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow

Answer (score 1):

[Kirualex](https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow)'s code is really nice, clean and easy to implement, thanks you. 
if anybody wants to stop the transition by touching the screen, when automatic slide is enabled, I added a boolean property 'addTouchStop'  into the KASlideShow.h and the following methods into the KASlideShow.m. inside the main viewController set this boolean property true.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if (addTouchStop) {

    [self stop];
}
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (addTouchStop) {
    [self start];
}
}
```