# IOS API to use to create app intro in a Flash way

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I need to create an intro for IOS app, I want to create transition between images like Macos X screensaver themes (beach, forest...) with music, and text appearing and fading. I don't know exactly which IOS API/framework is the most suitable to use to achieve this. I will appreciate suggestions or links to tutorials.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might give you some inspiration on at least how to get started:

[iphone fading of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618964/iphone-fading-of-images)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4M0BkJwLT0

Answer (score 1):

How about UIImageView and UILabel, with block animation?