# Fadout multiple image on splashscreen in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiimageview

I am trying to animate multiple image for splash screen.i am displaying 3 image as splash screen 1st one is default image of splash screen than by using Ui-imageview i am displaying 2nd and 3rd on my Imageview.

I want to fade out image while changing the splash screen. I tried NSTimmer solution but it display me direct 3rd image and maine screen Than after i tried This solution to have but it display me my 2nd and 3rd image 2 times one after another.
any help is appreciated

EDITED /- Nikki Suggest me some solution but i am having confusion that Which place i unhidden my 2nd image view ?
Here is my code

```
backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
backgroundImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SPLASHSCREEN-2.png"];
backgroundImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
backgroundImageView2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
backgroundImageView2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SPLASHSCREEN-3.png"];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView2];
[backgroundImageView2 setHidden:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(performTransition) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

-(void)performTransition
   {
CATransition *animation3 = [CATransition animation];
[animation3 setDuration:3.0f];
[animation3 setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[animation3 setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[backgroundImageView layer] addAnimation:animation3 forKey:@"SwitchToView"];
[backgroundImageView setHidden:YES];
[backgroundImageView2 setHidden:NO];//No animation happen while changing the image view
}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540300/fade-out-image-animation-in-iphone

Comment: @Rushabh He has already mension that NStimer trick is not usefull in his case. please read the question again.

Comment: @Rushabh well in NStimmer case it doesnt display the default image and it direct jump to 2nd image and than main screen.. 3rd splash screen and main screen is not displayed in NStimmer..i am going to add NStimer code in main question can you please suggest any solution

Answer (score 1):

U can create the two `ImageView` to be displayed in the start and set them hidden at first. Just write the code to animate :

```
-(void)performTransition
{  
  CATransition *animation3 =  [CATransition animation];
  [animation3  setDuration:3.0f];
  [animation3  setType:kCATransitionReveal];
  [animation3  setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
  [[backgroundImageView2  layer] addAnimation:animation3 forKey:@"SwitchToView"];
  [backgroundImageView  setHidden:YES];
  [backgroundImageView2  setHidden:NO];//No animation happen while changing the image view
}
```

and set the ImageView will animate while it unhides. The animation type can be changed by changing the values of `[animation3 setType:kCATransitionReveal];`.
Remember to import : `#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

for hiding the previous `ImageView` with animation and displaying next `ImageView` with animation you can write the code inside a function and can call that function using `performSelector` and can add desired time interval.

Comment: Can you help me I Have written code but their is some confusion..i am going to edit Main question Please help me if possible

Comment: @SwapAndroid - U need to write the image view to be unhidden in the code : `[[backgroundImageView layer] addAnimation:animation3 forKey:@"SwitchToView"];` which is `backgroundImageView2` and you have written `backgroundImageView`. You need to add the animation to the component's layer which you need to animate. Which is  `backgroundImageView2` in your case, not `backgroundImageView`.  Change the code. The animation will happen. Above written code by me does the same.

Comment: i tried as you said to change few lines of code and after that i does not display my splashscreen-2 it directly show splash screen-1 and after splash screen-3.. can you just paste you code here so i can get my concept clear more please.

Comment: just replace the performTransition funtion with my function in the above answer of mine. I have edited mu above answer.